# Replace cell values for each row and each column in Pandas using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iteration, nested-loops

I'm using python with pandas, but can also import any other library
Mu dataset has missing values (NaN) in thousands of rows in each column.

Examle

```
**Name,Type,Region...**
Oranges,Fruit,Western Europe  
NaN,NaN,NaN  
NaN,NaN,NaN  
Blueberry, berry,Easter Europe  
NaN,NaN,NaN 
Raspberry, berry,Easter Europe
NaN,NaN,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN
```

we can assume that the values in cells that have NaN can be re written to be the same as the previous value, until a new non NaN value is reached. Example:

```
**Name,Type,Region...**
Oranges,Fruit,Western Europe  
Oranges,Fruit,Western Europe 
Oranges,Fruit,Western Europe 
Blueberry, berry,Easter Europe  
Blueberry, berry,Easter Europe 
Raspberry, berry,Easter Europe  
Raspberry, berry,Easter Europe  
Raspberry, berry,Easter Europe
```

How can I iterate over each row value and each column to re-write the NaN values to match the first Non NaN value before it?

Rules:
if cell = NaN and previous_cell = not NaN, replace value with previous_cell,
if cell = NaN and previous_cell = NaN, continue (eliminating edge case when the whole column is empty)
if cell = NaN, continue

I have a huge dataset, so this is not possible to do manually in the CSV file itself

Nested query which does not work

Comment: [`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html

Comment: df.fillna(method="ffill")

Comment: @Nathan that exacly my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use apply with ffill for all clomuns it avaliable in pandas:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(df['Name'].shift())).ffill()
df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(df['Type'].shift())).ffill()
df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(df['Region'].shift())).ffill()
```